# Is it better to collect all test files into one folder, or just let them distribute everywhere?

Tags: python, unit-testing, testing, code-organization

Now I have a python project, I write my unit-testing code in many of its folders, the tree looks like:

```
Project
├── module1
│   ├── submodule1
│   │   ├── base.py
│   │   ├── model.py
│   │   └── tests.py
│   ├── conn.py
│   ├── __init__.py
│   └── tests.py
├── errors.py
├── __init__.py
├── router.py
└── tests.py
```

You can see there are many `tests.py` files in the projects, at root folder in modules. I use nose to help me do testing, When I want to test all of them, just run `nosetests Project` at upper folder, everything works fine.

Then comes to my question: I have seen some projects like tornado, they put all test files in one folder so that it is clear to manage them (I guess), is that a better way than what I do currently, if yes, then why ? And according to the philosophy of Python, is there anything wrong in my way of doing test ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Personnally, I prefer to store my test files into a specific subdirectory `test`, yet I like to keep test and code very near, so I have `test` subdirectories every where in my project.

```
 Project
    ├── module1
    │   ├── submodule1
    │   │   ├── base.py
    │   │   ├── model.py
    │   │   └── test
    │   │       └── submodule1_test.py
    │   ├── conn.py
    │   ├── __init__.py
    │   └── test
    │       └── module1_test.py
    ├── errors.py
    ├── __init__.py
    ├── router.py
    └── test
        └── errors_test.py
        └── router_test.py
```

Very easy to make a packaging with avoiding all tests directories.

Comment: Thanks for sharing your experience, could you tell me how to avoid test directories if `find_packages` is used in setup script ?

Comment: @Reorx : as [described here](http://packages.python.org/distribute/setuptools.html#using-find-packages) `find_packages(exclude=["*.test", "*.test.*", "test.*", "test"])` should works

Answer (score 1):

I put tests under a `/test` folder, separate from the source.  It makes packaging easier for those cases where I don't want to ship the test code.

Comment: If I put tests in each subdirectories, its also possible to ignore them when packaging, is there any other advantages of putting them together ?

Comment: Then it's just taste.  I prefer to keep the source and test code completely separate.  It sounds subjective.

Comment: Yeah I will try your suggestion, thanks very much ~